# Tensorflow Hub : Stuck while importing a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-hub

Trying to import some models with Tensorflow Hub with this code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

elmo_model = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=True)
```

Makes my notebook stuck. The only log line appearing before getting stuck is :

> INFO:tensorflow:Using /tmp/tfhub_modules to cache modules.

How to unstuck it and allow me to import models from Tensorflow Hub ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was simply about privileges : I couldn't access the default directory where Tensorflow Hub store the models (`/tmp/tfhub_modules`).

To solve it, I just choose a directory to store the models which I can access :

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

os.environ['TFHUB_CACHE_DIR'] = '/home/user/workspace/tf_cache'
elmo_model = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=True)
```

Comment: How did you find out that it was privileges issue?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, I just saw somewhere you could change this directory, and when I saw the default value, it strike me that it was not in my personal folder

Comment: Well done, this is hard to debug error. No error messages whatsoever.

Comment: What's odd for me is that I can write to /tmp and the /tmp/tfhub_modules folder exists. So Tensorflow was able to create the directory it wanted to but it still ended up failing silently down the road. Despite this, I still needed to change the TFHUB_CACHE_DIR to point to somewhere in my home directory for this to work